# Phonegap app does not resize or crashes on orientation change

Tags: android, css, responsive-design, cordova

**Platforms and tools:** using cordova 2.5.0, targeting android API levels 8-17.

**What I'm trying to do:** There are 5 slides, which are nothing but some text+images wrapped in`<div>` tags. Using jquery (not jqm) I adjust the `margin-bottom` of each slide with respect to the height of the slider window(again a big `<div>`), and slide them vertically. This works like honey, on the emulator.

**The reason of sleepless nights leading relationship issues:**
Jokes apart, App either crashes or doesn't respond to orientation change of device (not emulator!). If app is closed and started again, only the content text appears, without css. At this point, if I change the orientation of device,say portrait to landscape, everything looks perfect again as it should.

**Things I tried which didn't work:**

1)

```
android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

2)These are the media queries:

> @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px)

and (for landscape)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px)
```

and the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

3) I 'researched' about this on stack, google groups, but the problems were either unanswerd, or unaccepted, yet I have tried some of those too.

Please assist.

Comment: Why you didn't use the orientation:landscape in you @media query?

Comment: oh ok.. seems working!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:smallScreens="true"
   android:resizeable="true"
   android:anyDensity="true" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  >
    <activity
        android:name="com.XX.XXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize" > 
    </activity>

</application>
```